# TypeError: Parameters to generic types must be types. Got [3 2 31, 4 3 10]. Same code working on Pycharm but not on VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pycharm, jinja2, pdfkit

I have the following code,

```
from typing import List
import pdfkit
from pdfkit.api import configuration
from jinja2 import FileSystemLoader, Environment
wkhtml_path = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf = "C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf.exe")  #by using configuration you can add path value.



def generate_data():
    data = {}

    # For CS-1A
    data["CS-1A"] = [["" for i in range(5)] for j in range(5)]
    data["CS-1A"][0][0] += "Advance_Programming@Mr.Ashas@Room_#2 "
    data["CS-1A"][0][0] += "Applied_Physics@Bilal@Room_#1 "
    data["CS-1A"][0][1] += "Programming_Fundamentals@Muhammad_Bilal@Room_#1 "
    data["CS-1A"][0][3] += "Programming_Fundamentals_Lab@Mr._Abid@Lab_#01 "
    data["CS-1A"][0][4] += "Programming_Fundamentals_Lab@Mr._Abid@Lab_#01 "

    return data





def organise_input_data(elements: List[List[str]]) -> List[list]:
    """
    Organises the input data to find double courses for easier use in templates
    """
    new_elements = []
    for day in elements:
        last_course = None
        course_list = []
        index = 0
        for course in day:
            # cleanup data
            course = course.strip().replace(" ", "<hr>")
            # check if long course (and not lunch time)
            if course != "" and course == last_course and index != 3:
                course_list.remove((course, 1))
                course_list.append((course, 2))
                course_list.append(("none", 0))
            else:
                course_list.append((course.replace(" ", "<hr>"), 1))
            last_course = course
            index += 1
        new_elements.append(course_list)

    return new_elements


def generate_html(template, name: str, elements: List[list]) -> str:

    new_elements = organise_input_data(elements=elements)

    rendered = template.render(
        name=name,
        monday=new_elements[0],
        tuesday=new_elements[1],
        wednesday=new_elements[2],
        thursday=new_elements[3],
        friday=new_elements[4]
    )

    with open(f"out_{name}.html", "w+") as file:
        file.write(rendered)

    return rendered


def run(input_data):
    # Init jinja
    file_loader = FileSystemLoader('.')
    env = Environment(loader=file_loader)
    template = env.get_template('template.html')

    full_text = ""
    for name, elements in input_data.items():
        full_text += generate_html(template=template, name=name, elements=elements)

    pdfkit.from_string(full_text, "out.pdf", configuration = wkhtml_path)


dat = generate_data()


run(dat)
```

This is the `template.html` file,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <style>
.center
{
  text-align: center;

}
.left
{
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 6px;
    /*margin-top: 10px;*/
}
.right
{
    text-align: right;  margin-right: 4px;
}
.teacher
{
    margin-left: 4px;
}
td{
  height:175px;
  width:150px;
}


  </style>
<body>
<!-- Heading -->
    <h1 class="center">{{name}}</h1>

<!-- Table -->
    <table border="4" cellspacing="0" align="center">

<!-- Day/Periods -->
        <tr class = "header">
            <td class="center" ><br>
                <b>Day/Period</b></br>
            </td>
            <td class="center" >
                <b>I</b>
            </td>
            <td class="center" >
                <b>II</b>
            </td>
            <td class="center">
                <b>III</b>
            </td>
            <td class="center">
                <b>1:15-1:45</b>
            </td>
            <td class="center" >
                <b>IV</b>
            </td>
            <td class="center" >
                <b>V</b>
            </td>

        </tr>
<!-- Monday -->
        <tr>
            <td class="center">
                <b>Monday</b></td>
            {% for course in monday %}
                {% if loop.index == 4 %}
                    <td rowspan="6" class="center">
                        <h2>L<br>U<br>N<br>C<br>H</h2>
                    </td>
                {% endif %}
                {% if course[1] != 0 %}
                    <td colspan={{course[1]}}>
                        {% set count = [] %}
                        {%- for y in range(0, 5) -%}
                            {%- if count|length < course[0]|length -%}
                                <p class="left">
                            
                                    {%- for z in range(count|length, course[0]|length) -%}
                                        {%- if course[0][count|length] == '@' -%}
                                        {%- else -%}
                                            {% set __ = count.append(1) %}
                                            {%- if course[0][count|length-1] == '_' -%}
                                                {{' '}}
                                            {%- else -%}
                                                {{course[0][count|length-1]}}
                                            {%- endif -%}
                                        {%- endif -%}
                                    {%- endfor -%}
                                    </p>
                                    {% set __ = count.append(1) %}
                                    <p class = "right">
                                    {%- for z in range(count|length, course[0]|length) -%}
                                        {%- if course[0][count|length] == '@' -%}
                                        {%- else -%}
                                            {% set __ = count.append(1) %}
                                            {%- if course[0][count|length-1] == '_' -%}
                                                {{' '}}
                                            {%- else -%}
                                                {{course[0][count|length-1]}}
                                            {%- endif -%}
                                        {%- endif -%}
                                    {%- endfor -%}

                                </p>
                            {% set __ = count.append(1) %}
                        <p class = "teacher">
                        {%- for z in range(count|length, course[0]|length) -%}
                            {%- if course[0][count|length] == '@' -%}
                            {%- else -%}
                                {% set __ = count.append(1) %}
                                {%- if course[0][count|length-1] == '_' -%}
                                    {{' '}}
                                {%- else -%}
                                    {{course[0][count|length-1]}}
                                {%- endif -%}
                            {%- endif -%}
                        {%- endfor -%}  
                        </p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">{{course[0]}}</p>
                        <p class="right">{{course[1]}}</p>
                        <p class="teacher">{{course[2]}}</p> -->
                       {%- endif -%}
                      {%- endfor -%}    
                    </td>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}

        </tr>
<!-- Tuesday -->
        <tr>
            <td class="center">
                <b>Tuesday</b>
            </td>
            {% for course in tuesday %}
                {% if course[1] != 0 %}
                    <td colspan={{course[1]}}>
                        {% set count = [] %}
                        {%- for y in range(0, 5) -%}
                            {%- if count|length < course[0]|length -%}
                                <p class="left">
                            
                                    {%- for z in range(count|length, course[0]|length) -%}
                                        {%- if course[0][count|length] == '@' -%}
                                        {%- else -%}
                                            {% set __ = count.append(1) %}
                                            {%- if course[0][count|length-1] == '_' -%}
                                                {{' '}}
                                            {%- else -%}
                                                {{course[0][count|length-1]}}
                                            {%- endif -%}
                                        {%- endif -%}
                                    {%- endfor -%}
                                    </p>
                                    {% set __ = count.append(1) %}
                                    <p class = "right">
                                    {%- for z in range(count|length, course[0]|length) -%}
                                        {%- if course[0][count|length] == '@' -%}
                                        {%- else -%}
                                            {% set __ = count.append(1) %}
                                            {%- if course[0][count|length-1] == '_' -%}
                                                {{' '}}
                                            {%- else -%}
                                                {{course[0][count|length-1]}}
                                            {%- endif -%}
                                        {%- endif -%}
                                    {%- endfor -%}

                                </p>
                            {% set __ = count.append(1) %}
                        <p class = "teacher">
                        {%- for z in range(count|length, course[0]|length) -%}
                            {%- if course[0][count|length] == '@' -%}
                            {%- else -%}
                                {% set __ = count.append(1) %}
                                {%- if course[0][count|length-1] == '_' -%}
                                    {{' '}}
                                {%- else -%}
                                    {{course[0][count|length-1]}}
                                {%- endif -%}
                            {%- endif -%}
                        {%- endfor -%}  
                        </p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">{{course[0]}}</p>
                        <p class="right">{{course[1]}}</p>
                        <p class="teacher">{{course[2]}}</p> -->
                       {%- endif -%}
                      {%- endfor -%}    
                    </td>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
<!-- Wednesday -->
        <tr>
            <td class="center">
                <b>Wednesday</b>
            </td>
            {% for course in wednesday %}
                {% if course[1] != 0 %}
                    <td colspan={{course[1]}}>
                        {% set count = [] %}
                        {%- for y in range(0, 5) -%}
                            {%- if count|length < course[0]|length -%}
                                <p class="left">
                            
                                    {%- for z in range(count|length, course[0]|length) -%}
                                        {%- if course[0][count|length] == '@' -%}
                                        {%- else -%}
                                            {% set __ = count.append(1) %}
                                            {%- if course[0][count|length-1] == '_' -%}
                                                {{' '}}
                                            {%- else -%}
                                                {{course[0][count|length-1]}}
                                            {%- endif -%}
                                        {%- endif -%}
                                    {%- endfor -%}
                                    </p>
                                    {% set __ = count.append(1) %}
                                    <p class = "right">
                                    {%- for z in range(count|length, course[0]|length) -%}
                                        {%- if course[0][count|length] == '@' -%}
                                        {%- else -%}
                                            {% set __ = count.append(1) %}
                                            {%- if course[0][count|length-1] == '_' -%}
                                                {{' '}}
                                            {%- else -%}
                                                {{course[0][count|length-1]}}
                                            {%- endif -%}
                                        {%- endif -%}
                                    {%- endfor -%}

                                </p>
                            {% set __ = count.append(1) %}
                        <p class = "teacher">
                        {%- for z in range(count|length, course[0]|length) -%}
                            {%- if course[0][count|length] == '@' -%}
                            {%- else -%}
                                {% set __ = count.append(1) %}
                                {%- if course[0][count|length-1] == '_' -%}
                                    {{' '}}
                                {%- else -%}
                                    {{course[0][count|length-1]}}
                                {%- endif -%}
                            {%- endif -%}
                        {%- endfor -%}  
                        </p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">{{course[0]}}</p>
                        <p class="right">{{course[1]}}</p>
                        <p class="teacher">{{course[2]}}</p> -->
                       {%- endif -%}
                      {%- endfor -%}    
                    </td>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
<!-- Thursday -->
        <tr>
            <td class="center">
                <b>Thursday</b>
            </td>
            {% for course in thursday %}
                {% if course[1] != 0 %}
                    <td colspan={{course[1]}}>
                        {% set count = [] %}
                        {%- for y in range(0, 5) -%}
                            {%- if count|length < course[0]|length -%}
                                <p class="left">
                            
                                    {%- for z in range(count|length, course[0]|length) -%}
                                        {%- if course[0][count|length] == '@' -%}
                                        {%- else -%}
                                            {% set __ = count.append(1) %}
                                            {%- if course[0][count|length-1] == '_' -%}
                                                {{' '}}
                                            {%- else -%}
                                                {{course[0][count|length-1]}}
                                            {%- endif -%}
                                        {%- endif -%}
                                    {%- endfor -%}
                                    </p>
                                    {% set __ = count.append(1) %}
                                    <p class = "right">
                                    {%- for z in range(count|length, course[0]|length) -%}
                                        {%- if course[0][count|length] == '@' -%}
                                        {%- else -%}
                                            {% set __ = count.append(1) %}
                                            {%- if course[0][count|length-1] == '_' -%}
                                                {{' '}}
                                            {%- else -%}
                                                {{course[0][count|length-1]}}
                                            {%- endif -%}
                                        {%- endif -%}
                                    {%- endfor -%}

                                </p>
                            {% set __ = count.append(1) %}
                        <p class = "teacher">
                        {%- for z in range(count|length, course[0]|length) -%}
                            {%- if course[0][count|length] == '@' -%}
                            {%- else -%}
                                {% set __ = count.append(1) %}
                                {%- if course[0][count|length-1] == '_' -%}
                                    {{' '}}
                                {%- else -%}
                                    {{course[0][count|length-1]}}
                                {%- endif -%}
                            {%- endif -%}
                        {%- endfor -%}  
                        </p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">{{course[0]}}</p>
                        <p class="right">{{course[1]}}</p>
                        <p class="teacher">{{course[2]}}</p> -->
                       {%- endif -%}
                      {%- endfor -%}    
                    </td>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}

        </tr>
<!-- Friday -->
        <tr>
            <td class="center">
                <b>Friday</b>
            </td>
            {% for course in friday %}
                {% if course[1] != 0 %}
                    <td colspan={{course[1]}}>
                        {% set count = [] %}
                        {%- for y in range(0, 5) -%}
                            {%- if count|length < course[0]|length -%}
                                <p class="left">
                            
                                    {%- for z in range(count|length, course[0]|length) -%}
                                        {%- if course[0][count|length] == '@' -%}
                                        {%- else -%}
                                            {% set __ = count.append(1) %}
                                            {%- if course[0][count|length-1] == '_' -%}
                                                {{' '}}
                                            {%- else -%}
                                                {{course[0][count|length-1]}}
                                            {%- endif -%}
                                        {%- endif -%}
                                    {%- endfor -%}
                                    </p>
                                    {% set __ = count.append(1) %}
                                    <p class = "right">
                                    {%- for z in range(count|length, course[0]|length) -%}
                                        {%- if course[0][count|length] == '@' -%}
                                        {%- else -%}
                                            {% set __ = count.append(1) %}
                                            {%- if course[0][count|length-1] == '_' -%}
                                                {{' '}}
                                            {%- else -%}
                                                {{course[0][count|length-1]}}
                                            {%- endif -%}
                                        {%- endif -%}
                                    {%- endfor -%}

                                </p>
                            {% set __ = count.append(1) %}
                        <p class = "teacher">
                        {%- for z in range(count|length, course[0]|length) -%}
                            {%- if course[0][count|length] == '@' -%}
                            {%- else -%}
                                {% set __ = count.append(1) %}
                                {%- if course[0][count|length-1] == '_' -%}
                                    {{' '}}
                                {%- else -%}
                                    {{course[0][count|length-1]}}
                                {%- endif -%}
                            {%- endif -%}
                        {%- endfor -%}  
                        </p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">{{course[0]}}</p>
                        <p class="right">{{course[1]}}</p>
                        <p class="teacher">{{course[2]}}</p> -->
                       {%- endif -%}
                      {%- endfor -%}    
                    </td>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}

        </tr>

    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

The same code, when I run it in `pycharm`, it works well.

But whenever I run it on `VS Code`, it is giving me this error for I don't know what reason,

```
TypeError: Parameters to generic types must be types. Got [3 2 31, 4 3 10].
```

The error is coming at this line,

```
def organise_input_data(elements: List[List[str]]) -> List[list]:
```

Can anyone guide me how can I solve this? I believe I have installed all the required libraries on my VS Code.

The Version of **VS Code** is **1.63.2 (user setup)** (as found from Help -> About)

```
Version: 1.63.2 (user setup)
Commit: 899d46d82c4c95423fb7e10e68eba52050e30ba3
Date: 2021-12-15T09:40:02.816Z
Electron: 13.5.2
Chromium: 91.0.4472.164
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19042
```

The version of **Pycharm** is **2020.1.2 Community Edition**

```
PyCharm 2020.1.2 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-201.7846.77, built on June 1, 2020
Runtime version: 11.0.7+10-b765.53 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 10 10.0
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 920M
Cores: 4
```

Comment: Please post here the Python version used by VsCode and that used by PyCharm.

Comment: @BesDollma I have added the versions of both at the end. Thank you.

Comment: I have tried your code, without the pdfkit, and I can't reproduce the error with Python 3.6, you should definitely look at the template

Comment: @rioV8 I commented out the pdfkit import commands and also the `run` function (which had pdfkit line). I tried to run the program and it still gave the same error. It is not even declaring that function for me... I ran `py -3 --version` command to check my Python version on VS Code and it shows `Python 3.9.2`

Comment: `List[list]` has a lower case `l`, maybe that is the problem, `list` is not a type, `List` is a type

Comment: @rioV8 That solved it! Thank you so much! I would never have gotten it :/